# Link exchange with nofollow noindex bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, backlinks, technical-seo, negative-seo

I have different websites A and B but the same niche. Some users visiting website A has interesting to buy products on website B and vice versa.

So, I thought to exchange backlinks on both sites and it helps users to buy both products on both sites.

I know that the link exchange is not good for SEO and that's why I make those backlinks no follow, no index.

But my problem is, does it still affect the rankings even if I provide them no follow, and no index?

Answer (score 2):

I think it doesn't matter at all but the important thing is that you should create natural links according to the real needs of your website users.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in link exchange. People can always link to each other if they find any value addition and Google will not have any issues with that, if the links are natural and do not look spammy.

In case you still wish Google not to consider linking then noindex wil do the trick.